# Passbook (Wallet) with ibeacons

Tags: swift, ibeacon

I bought few iBeacons today and started playing with ios SDK.
I read in one of the apple forum that we can build and distribute a Apple Passbook pass to users and it can show notification to user when it detects a specific iBeacon.(https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6028034?tstart=0) This feature don't need any app to be installed on the user mobile device. Is this a correct info?

I have been searching the web for exact reference and unfortunately cant find anything very specific to this except sites like passkit.com who promises to build such passbook pass and distribute for you, but since its paid can't try.

Any help/info/reference will be really helpful which can help be build from scratch.

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible to send a notification  about a Passbook pass to an iOS user when they come near a beacon.**  They do not need a special app to do this (just the Passbook app, which is pre-installed).  The user, however, does need to have installed the pass just like any other Passbook pass.

This works by embedding beacon identifier information in the pass itself.  When the Passbook app installs the pass. It starts looking for that beacon in the background.  When the device comes across it, the Passbook app sends a notification to the user.

My colleague wrote a detailed blog post about how to do this [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/10/06/passkit-with-beacons.html).  **No payment required!**

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what i was looking for.